# In wordpress how to sent different email separetly when i click on different email ids

Tags: plugins, email, plugin-contact-form-7

I am using contact form 7 as a plugin in wordpress but i dont know how to sent different email separetly when i click on different email ids

Comment: what do you mean by "when i click on different email ids "?

Comment: @Bainternet there are three mail ids like abc@mail.com, xyz@mail.com, qwerty@mail.com so when i click on abc@mail.com link it opens a contact form and after submission the mail should go to abc@mail.com only like that when i click on qwerty@mail.com link it opens a contact form and after submission the mail should go to qwerty@mail.com... i am using contact form 7 so the mails are sent to only one mail only any help ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The documentation for Contact 7 is pretty clear about how to do this - you just need to create a separate mail template for each form and edit the basic header fields

http://contactform7.com/setting-up-mail/